# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in run line = line.split('\t')

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7, byte

I'm using Python 3.7 (64-bit), and I run into the following error when running the code:

in run
    line = line.split('\t')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

The code I'm trying to run is the following:

```
    out_path = os.getcwd() + "/" + self.options['output folder'] + "/"
    out_file_name = out_path + "decision_log__" + self.options['input file']

    out_file = open(out_file_name, 'w')
    self.output_files['log'] = out_file

    tm_file = open(input_file_path, 'rb')
    if self.have_alignment is True:
        tm_align_file = open(align_file_path, 'r')
    if self.have_token is True:
        tm_token_file = open(token_file_path, 'rb')

    line_no = 0
    for line in tm_file:
        line_no += 1
        line = line.split("\t")
```

Originally, the codes were programmed in Python 2.7, then I used 2to3 to translate the files into the newest, 3.x, syntax.

What is the root of this issue and how can I fix it most effectively?

Best regards,
Adam

Comment: `line = line.split(b"\t")`

Comment: To expand on Aran's comment; The reason for this error is because you've opened the file 'rb' ie binary, so read functions on the file return 'bytes' objects not str's. The result is that they have to be compared with bytes objects (such as b"\t") not str's. If the file contains only utf-8 characters you might want to consider changer the open line to `tm_file = open(input_file_path, 'r')`